# MySQL take so long to execute the select with subquery?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

When I was connecting to the Aurora MySQL, I try the following SQL

```
SELECT date, eventid
FROM `vw_KissMetricsAnalytics`
where eventid IN ( LOTS_OF_NUMS )
```

It only takes only 1 seconds, but when I change the SQL to

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT date, eventid
FROM `vw_KissMetricsAnalytics`
where eventid IN ( LOTS_OF_NUMS )
) s;
```

and this takes forever to run, isn't that they should be the same? Will that be the limitation of usable memory? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You would think that MySQL should realize that the outer query adds nothing to the result, and the optimizer should just factor it out. But it doesn't.

Writing a subquery in the `FROM` clause like you show creates a **temporary table** that is filled with the result of the subquery.

The temporary table must be converted into rows, stored somewhere (depending on the number of rows, either in memory or on disk) temporarily, and then the outer query reads that temporary table to give you the final result.

This adds a lot of overhead to the whole operation, and slows down your work.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yeah I am thinking this as well but I am wondering that in the first SQL, the results of all rows need to be moved to the buffer as well, and if we run the second SQL then it just results in twice the space and it should take like twice or 3 times of the time of the previous SQL right? And I actually execute the second SQL command after the first one, the result should be in the buffer already so it shouldn't take that long right? Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that creating the temp table is quite expensive, so it's something to be avoided if you can.

Comment: Because I am doing pivoting in MySQL, and I search online, the way to do it needs a subquery

Comment: @linjunshi incidentally, a nice way to show 'thanks' around here is by upvoting and/or accepting an answer